# Angular js .push method for Json file not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When i try to enter random data into an Array or Json file through .push method its not working 
here is my code
Array Code is

```
 $scope.stock =[{
"name":"Pepsi",
"price":65,
"color":"black",
"avaliable":true}]
```

trying to bind through ng-model

```
<form ng-submit="addItem()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="newName" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price" ng-model="newPrice" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="color" ng-model="newcolor" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add New Item" />
</form>
```

the JS code is

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.stock.push({
        name: $scope.newName,
        price: parseInt($scope.newPrice),
        color: $scope.newcolor,
        avaliable: true
    });
```

Comment: Did you get any error? I think your code looks good

Comment: Did you initialise $scope.stock=[];

Comment: didn't give me any thing?

Comment: ohhh i got that Mistake 
i have to initialize

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//try this
$scope.stock = [];

$scope.addItem = function(){
$scope.stock.push({
    name: $scope.newName,
    price: parseInt($scope.newPrice),
    color: $scope.newcolor,
    avaliable: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for angular 1.4.6 please check here [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dqgcmvx9/1/)

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngStorage']).controller('ctrl',
  function($scope, $localStorage) {

    $scope.stock = [{
      "name": "Pepsi",
      "price": 65,
      "color": "black",
      "avaliable": true
    }]

    $scope.addItem = function() {
      $scope.stock.push({
        name: $scope.newName,
        price: parseInt($scope.newPrice),
        color: $scope.newcolor,
        avaliable: true
      });
    }
  });
```